# Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-permissions

Im using react-native-permissions in ios build emulator (iphone 14 pro)
but build always fails with error

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'RNPermissionsModule' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary., js engine: hermes

I added
pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
to my Podfile
but that doesn't solve my problem

Comment: What's your Xcode version? If 14.3, try downgrading to 14.2

Comment: my xcode is 14.3.1 but i managed the solve the problem without downgrading

Answer (score 0):

I Foud A solution by adding

```
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}

    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNPermissions') || pod.name.start_with?('Permission-')
        def pod.build_type;
          # Uncomment the line corresponding to your CocoaPods version
          # Pod::BuildType.static_library # >= 1.9
          # Pod::Target::BuildType.static_library # < 1.9
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

after use_frameworks! to PodFile   and adding

```
"reactNativePermissionsIOS": [
    "LocationAccuracy",
    "LocationAlways",
    "LocationWhenInUse",
    "MediaLibrary",
    "Notifications",
    "PhotoLibrary"
  ],
```

to package.json  and running
react-native setup-ios-permissions && pod-install